# Querying XML with LINQ and using null in place of a particular xml attribute if it does not exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a model class

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Desc {get; set;}
}
```

I would query my XML document

```
List<Item> item = xmlDoc.Descendants()
    .Select(o => new Item { 
        Name = o.Attribute("name").Value, 
        Desc = o.Attribute("desc").Value
    }).ToList();
```

However, the attribute *desc* may or may not be present for each item. The above LINQ works if the attribute *desc* is present, but will cause an exception if not.

If it does not exist I would like for the LINQ query to just assign *null* to the *Desc* field in the new *Item* object. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/896292c1-1975-4a13-aa81-dacd973f35c8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to do this is with the conversion operators:

```
Name = (string) o.Attribute("name"),
Desc = (string) o.Attribute("desc")
```

why is this the preferred way? Firstly, it is easy; and secondly, it works correctly for other types:

```
Count = (int?) o.Attribute("count"),
When = (DateTime?) o.Attribute("when")
```

In particular, these also apply the correct xml encoding rules for each data type, rather than using a culture-specific `DateTime.Parse` / `int.Parse` etc. Lots of subtle things to not want to remember!

Note that if you want to assert that the attribute exists, the non-`Nullable<T>` versions work too:

```
Size = (int) o.Attribute("size"),
Created = (DateTime) o.Attribute("created")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator - [?:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
List<Item> item = xmlDoc.Descendants() 
    .Select(o => new Item {  
        Name = o.Attribute("name") != null ? o.Attribute("name").Value : null,  
        Desc = o.Attribute("desc") != null ? o.Attribute("desc").Value : null,
    }).ToList();
```